# limit number of repeated characters with jQuery but leave period alone

Tags: jquery, input, limit

I'm using this code to avoid user repeat a character more then 3 times in a row ("bbb","ddd" or so...):

```js
$('.limitRepeaters').keypress(function(){
  if (/(.)\1{2,}/.test($(this).val())) {
   return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="limitRepeaters">
```

Now i want the user to be able to repeat the "period" charcter three times (...) so i tried:

```js
$('.limitRepeaters').keypress(function(e){
   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if ((/(.)\1{2,}/.test($(this).val())) && (code != '190')) {
   return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="limitRepeaters">
```

But that doesn't seem to work. any ideas?

**EDIT**

I now get the problem. actually when the user he is typing a letter after writing "..." is not typing the 190 key code so the 190 keycode needs to be added to the regex itself. any idea how to do that?

Comment: Your dot is any characters including the dot.

Escape it if you need to use the dot itself

Answer (score 0):

Use the same block that you mentioned but with below changes.

```
$('.limitRepeaters').keypress(function(){
var str = $(this).val();
  if (/(.)\1{2,}/.test(str.replace(/[...]/g,''))) {
   return false;
  }
});
```

In the above code I have replaced all occurences of (...) in the string. If you dont want all occurences use `if (/(.)\1{2,}/.test(str.replace('...',''))) {`

Comment: That's great, thanks. but the problem here is it will let the user repeat the period six times and i do want to limit it to three, just let him continue writing afterwords... so if he writes "bbb" it wont let him write any more, but if he writes "..." it will let him continue with any other letter (not period) and of course that he will be able to write another period in the text, just not right after the three periods.

Comment: the first solution will let the user write unlimited periods. the second one will let him write six. and then if he will write period a second time it will let him write only two.

Answer (score 0):

for now what if got is:

```js
$('.limitRepeaters').keypress(function(){
var str = $(this).val();
  if (/(.)\1{2,}/.test(str.replace(/[...]/g,'')) || /(.)\1{3,}/.test($(this).val())) {
   return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="limitRepeaters"/>
```

Which seems a little bit long and also will let the user write period 4 times (but that's not that bad...). any shorter idea will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

To test if any character is repeating 3 times or more, except the `.` , `/([^.])\1{3,}/` can be used. However in the current implementation, backspaces or other characters aren't allowed either once the match is reached.

An alternative would be to reset to the old value in keyup, although this is a bit 'jerky' (a more streamlined solution would be to generated the expected value with the cursor position and pressed key, but functionally the below is easier)

```js
var oldValue;
$('.limitRepeaters').keypress(function(e){
 oldValue=  {val : this.value, pos : this.selectionStart }; //strictly speaking selectionEnd should be kept as well
}).keyup(function(e){
 if (/([^.])\1{3,}/.test(this.value)) {
   this.value = oldValue.val;
    this.selectionStart = oldValue.pos;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="limitRepeaters">
```

Then again, perhaps blocking all other input once three repeating characters are entered is the goal and this is not needed at all :) . In that case `/([^.])\1{3,}/` can be used directly in the existing code.